# Why am I not getting the scrollTop value?

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I want to get the *scrollTop* value of an element so I can trigger other things depending on that. The client should always check the *scrollTop* value, so I am using *onscroll* to run the function. It does not work, I always get 0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onscroll="get_y_pos();">
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div id="element_to_watch" style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: blue; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
  <script>
    function get_y_pos() {
      var pos = document.getElementById('element_to_watch').scrollTop;
      console.log(pos);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have misunderstood what `scrollTop` is. This property gives you the scroll offset, when you scroll _inside_ an element that has scrollbars, due to its content overflowing the defined height. Your `element_to_watch` does not have any overflowing content and no scrollbars here.

Comment: I think `getBoundingClientRect().top` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I thought: The window has scrollbars. When I scroll down the element_to_watch goes up the window, so it does have an overflowing content.

Comment: No, that is an absolutely wrong understanding of the whole thing. _“so it does have an overflowing content”_ - the window (more correct, the html or body element) is the one that has overflowing content here, not `element_to_watch`.

Comment: I think here is a good example on how it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @bertida, to achieve this, `getBoundingClientRect().top` should be used instead of `scrollTop`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onscroll="get_y_pos();">
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div id="element_to_watch" style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: blue; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
  <script>
    function get_y_pos() {
      var pos = document.getElementById('element_to_watch').getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(pos);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as someone already said you would need to add a vertical scrollbar to the element in order to check its `scrollTop` value. Check the updated Code Snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body onscroll="get_y_pos();" style="overflow: visible;">
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div id="element_to_watch" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background: blue; margin: 20px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <h1 style="height: 500px">Hallo</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 400px; width: 300px; background: red; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
  <script>
    function get_y_pos() {
      var pos = document.getElementById('element_to_watch');
      console.log(pos.scrollTop);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```